# Game theory problem - two towers

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I'm asking that question because I still cannot figure out the solution after hours of thinking.

You are given two towers where first has exactly *n* stones and second has exactly *m* stones. You are also given a number *k*. During each round you can perform one of the actions listed below:

- take exactly *k* stones from the first tower,
- take exactly *k* stones from the second tower,
- take exactly *k* stones from both towers.

There are two players: A and B. Player A starts. The winner is the player who has performed last possible action. How to determine after given *n, m, k* numbers who has winning strategy (who will win independently from opponent moves).

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan the link you attached is for problem where you should take *k* stones at turn, but  there's no such requirement at all there to take that amount at every turn

Comment: My bad, I should have read it better. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wythoff%27s_game may help you.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide through by $k$, equvalently making $k=1$.
Let $m=xk+a, n=yk+b$, with both $a$ and $b$ between $0$ and $ k-1$.  Then the $a$ and $b$ stones left over play no part in the game.  Every round, you reduce either $x$, $y$ or both by $1$.
So let $k=1$.  Which positions with $y=0$ are wins, and which are losses ?  If $y=1$, can you put the position into a lost position for your opponent ?  So which positions are wins when $y=1$?  Then do $y=2$, and so on.